# re pattern to include year of dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have some issues with the re pattern to include the year of dates.

#### Code

```
import re

text ="May 2020 Musical Portraits September 24 - 25, 2021 Time: 8:00 pm Toledo Museum of Art Peristyle  Romeo & JulietSpecial EventWhenFriday, Mar 23 / 20187:30pmBuy TicketsSunday, Mar 25 / 20182:30pmBuy TicketsWhereSamford University Wright CenterMap & DirectionsArtist"
format_list = ["(?:(?:(?:j|J)an)|(?:(?:f|F)eb)|(?:(?:m|M)ar)|(?:(?:a|A)pr)|(?:(?:m|M)ay)|(?:(?:j|J)un)|(?:(?:j|J)ul)|(?:(?:a|A)ug)|(?:(?:s|S)ep)|(?:(?:o|O)ct)|(?:(?:n|N)ov)|(?:(?:d|D)ec))\w*(?:\s)?(?:\n)?[0-9]{1,2}(?:\s)?(?:\,|\.|\/|\-)?(?:\s)?[0-9]{2,4}(?:\,|\.|\/|\-)?(?:\s)?[0-9]{2,4}"]

all_dates=[]

for pattern in format_list:
    all_dates = re.findall(pattern, text)
    if all_dates == []:
        continue
    else:
        for index,txt in enumerate(all_dates):
            text = re.sub('([^\x00-\x7F]+)|(\n)|(\t)',' ', txt)
            all_dates[index] = text
    print(all_dates)
```

#### Output

```
['September 24 - 25, 2021', 'Mar 23 / 20187', 'Mar 25 / 20182']
```

#### Desired Output

```
['September 24 - 25, 2021', 'Mar 23 / 2018', 'Mar 25 / 2018']
```

#### Issue

Instead of `"…2018"`, I'm getting `"…20187"` and `"…20182"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern may do the job you need

```
(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\w{0,6}\s+[\d\s\-\\/,]+?\d{4}
```

Code:

```
import re

text ="May 2020 Musical Portraits September 24 - 25, 2021 Time: 8:00 pm Toledo Museum of Art Peristyle  Romeo & JulietSpecial EventWhenFriday, Mar 23 / 20187:30pmBuy TicketsSunday, Mar 25 / 20182:30pmBuy TicketsWhereSamford University Wright CenterMap & DirectionsArtist"
format_list  = [
    # r"(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\w{0,6}[\d\s\-\\/,]*?\d{4}",  # If you want to also match e.g. May 2020
    r"(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\w{0,6}\s+[\d\s\-\\/,]+?\d{4}",
]

for pattern in format_list:
    all_dates = re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
    print(all_dates)
```

Output:

```
['September 24 - 25, 2021', 'Mar 23 / 2018', 'Mar 25 / 2018']
```

Where:

- `(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)` - Match the prefix of the months
- `\w{0,6}` - Match the full name of a month optionally, the longest being "sep" (from previous match) + "tember"
- `\s+` - Match 1 or more spaces.
- `[\d\s\-\\/,]+?` - Match the days part whether separated by space, dash, or slash.
- `\d{4}` - Match the year part.

Note that since regex is just string-based processing, you would be limited with the format `"mon day, year"` here. You would need additional patterns to match different possible date formats. You might want to explore date parsers that can scan through text.

Comment: How can we avoid May 2020 from that list ?

Comment: @Aniiya0978 you can just use the 2nd pattern. To avoid confusion, I commented out the first pattern in my answer. Could you check if it works on your side?

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the last `(?:\,|\.|\/|\-)?(?:\s)?[0-9]{2,4}` from your `format_list` and it should work fine. Just use the `format_list` below.

```py
format_list = ["(?:(?:(?:j|J)an)|(?:(?:f|F)eb)|(?:(?:m|M)ar)|(?:(?:a|A)pr)|(?:(?:m|M)ay)|(?:(?:j|J)un)|(?:(?:j|J)ul)|(?:(?:a|A)ug)|(?:(?:s|S)ep)|(?:(?:o|O)ct)|(?:(?:n|N)ov)|(?:(?:d|D)ec))\w*(?:\s)?(?:\n)?[0-9]{1,2}(?:\s)?(?:\,|\.|\/|\-)?(?:\s)?[0-9]{2,4}"]
```

Comment: It will drop the year part for the first date.

Comment: If there is month and year alone like May 2020, then it will also get detected with this pattern. I am trying for a bit tighter pattern

Comment: @Aniiya0978 try to explain what you are trying to accomplish. what do you mean by tighter pattern.

Comment: @adamkwm Oh i didn't see that one, lemme try to fix it.